# Pandas Conditionally Combine (and sum) Rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                'B':[1,1,2,1,1,1],
                'C':[2,4,6,3,5,7]})
df

    A   B   C
0   A   1   2
1   A   1   4
2   A   2   6
3   B   1   3
4   B   1   5
5   B   1   7
```

Wherever there are duplicate rows per columns 'A' and 'B', I'd like to combine those rows and sum the value under column 'C' like this:

```
    A   B   C
0   A   1   6
2   A   2   6
3   B   1   15
```

So far, I can at least identify the duplicates like this:

```
df['Dup']=df.duplicated(['A','B'],keep=False)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `groupby()` and `sum()`:

```
In [94]: df.groupby(['A','B']).sum().reset_index()
Out[94]:
   A  B   C
0  A  1   6
1  A  2   6
2  B  1  15
```